# Create a new dataframe in R resulting from comparison of differently ordered columns from two other databases with different lengths

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison

I have this two dataframe CDD26_FF (5593 rows) and CDD_HI (5508 rows) having a structure (columns) like below. CDDs are "consecutive dry days", and the two table show species exposure to CDD in far future (FF) and historical period (HI).

I want to focus only on "Biom" and "Species_name" columnes.

As you can see the two table have same "Species_names" and same "Biom" (areas in the world with sama climatic conditions). "Biom" values goes from 0 to 15. By the way, "Species_name" do not always appear in both tables (e.g. Abromoco_ben); Furthemore, the two tables not always have the combinations of "Species_name" and "Biom" (combinations are simply population of the same species belonging to that Biom)

CDD26_FF :

| CDD26_FF | AreaCell | Area_total | Biom | Species_name | AreaCellSuAreaTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 13 | 10 | Abrocomo_ben | 0.076923 |
| 1 | 1 | 8 | 1 | Abrocomo_cin | 0.125000 |
| 1 | 1 | 30 | 10 | Abrocomo_cin | 0.033333 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | 1 | Abrothrix_an | 0.200000 |
| 1 | 1 | 44 | 10 | Abrothrix_an | 0.022727 |
| 1 | 3 | 6 | 2 | Abrothrix_je | 0.500000 |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | 12 | Abrothrix_lo | 0.142857 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |

CDD_HI

| CDD_HI | AreaCell | Area_total | Biom | Species_name | AreaCellSuAreaTot_HI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8 | 1 | Abrocomo_cin | 0.125000 |
| 1 | 5 | 30 | 10 | Abrocomo_cin | 0.166666 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 2 | Abrocomo_cin | 0.200000 |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 1 | Abrothrix_an | 0.100000 |
| 1 | 1 | 44 | 10 | Abrothrix_an | 0.022727 |
| 1 | 6 | 18 | 1 | Abrothrix_je | 0.333333 |
| 1 | 1 | 23 | 4 | Abrothrix_lo | 0.130434 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |

I want to highlight rows that have same matches of "Species_name" and "Biom": in the example they are lines 3, 4, 5 from CDD26_FF matching lines 2, 4, 5 from CDD_HI, respectively. I want to store these line in a new table, but I want to store not only "Species_name" and "Biom" column (as "compare()" function seems to do), but also all the other columns.

More precisely, I want then to calculate the ratio of "AreaCellSuAreaTot" / "AreaCellSuAreaTot_HI" from the highlighted lines.

How can I do that?
Aside from "compare()", I tried a "for" loop, but lengths of the table differ, so I tried with a 3-nested for loop, still without results.  I also tried "compareDF()" and "semi_join()". No results untill now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible sample of your dataset?

Comment: Yes, I did not know how to upload them. I made a GDrive link. Here it is: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17R1b8ZC7NS_JP7DqDL7hNoTCDAU3yUS6?usp=sharing if you prefer another way to share, tell me how. I'm kind of new in the forum

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inner join (provided by `dplyr`). An inner join returns all datasets that are present in both tables/data.frames and with matching conditions (in this case: matching "Biom" and "Species_name").

Subsequently it's easy to calculate some ratio using `mutate`:

```r
library(dplyr)

cdd26_f %>%
  inner_join(cdd_hi, by=c("Biom", "Species_name")) %>%
  mutate(ratio = AreaCellSuAreaTotal/AreaCellSuAreaTot_HI) %>%
  select(Biom, Species_name, ratio)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 3
   Biom Species_name ratio
  <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
1     1 Abrocomo_cin 1    
2    10 Abrocomo_cin 0.200
3     1 Abrothrix_an 2    
4    10 Abrothrix_an 1
```

Note: Remove the `select`-part, if you need all columns or manipulate it for other columns.

### Data

```r
cdd26_f <- readr::read_table2("CDD26_FF     AreaCell    Area_total  Biom    Species_name    AreaCellSuAreaTotal
1   1   13  10  Abrocomo_ben    0.076923
1   1   8   1   Abrocomo_cin    0.125000
1   1   30  10  Abrocomo_cin    0.033333
1   2   10  1   Abrothrix_an    0.200000
1   1   44  10  Abrothrix_an    0.022727
1   3   6   2   Abrothrix_je    0.500000
1   1   7   12  Abrothrix_lo    0.142857")

cdd_hi <- readr::read_table2("CDD_HI    AreaCell    Area_total  Biom    Species_name    AreaCellSuAreaTot_HI
1   1   8   1   Abrocomo_cin    0.125000
1   5   30  10  Abrocomo_cin    0.166666
1   1   5   2   Abrocomo_cin    0.200000
1   1   10  1   Abrothrix_an    0.100000
1   1   44  10  Abrothrix_an    0.022727
1   6   18  1   Abrothrix_je    0.333333
1   1   23  4   Abrothrix_lo    0.130434")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the join() function is very clear.

Comment: Feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it helped you solving your problem.